# How to query the current Jenkins LTS version number?

Tags: jenkins, get, version, lts

How to get programatically the version number designated as the current LTS release of Jenkins, one of a list of weekly release numbers?

The [Jenkins download page](https://jenkins.io/download/) has text to indicate the current version designated as LTS (e.g., 2.46.2). 
To download the current Jenkins LTS release binary for Ubuntu, there are two choices:

- distro-specific packages, which contain the version in their name so as to not be ambiguous.
- generic war file, which does not contain version number to permit a constant download target that presumably is guaranteed to link to the current version as it changes over time.

I am looking for a means of programatically getting the version number, so that it can be used to:

- Check the current version to detect updates
- Describe the generic war file
- Complete a file name to retrieve that contains the version number

I am hoping there is a single file that contains the authoritative version  value somewhere on the Jenkins.io site, that can be queried via cURL or some such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jenkins update center [1] provides the latest release numbers

- For stable (LTS) https://updates.jenkins.io/stable/latestCore.txt
- And for the latest https://updates.jenkins.io/latestCore.txt

So, a simple `curl -Ls https://updates.jenkins.io/stable/latestCore.txt` should do the trick of retrieving the latest LTS version number.

[1] https://updates.jenkins.io/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The currently accepted answer relies on a specific HTML implementation in order for its various pipes and sed to work.  This instead goes to the simplest source.

Comment: Checked and Accepted, as preferable to previous solution.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing this message you can find the stable releases under this url

http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/

Something like this can give you the version and a link to the WAR file

```
LATEST_JENKINS_LTS_VERSION=$(curl -s http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/ | grep DIR | tail -n2 | head -n1 | sed 's/^.*href="//; s/\/".*//')

LATEST_JENKINS_LTS_WAR="http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/${LATEST_JENKINS_LTS_VERSION/}/jenkins.war"
```

Alternatively if you just need a link to the latest jenkins war file use this url

http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war

Comment: I tried to add this to your answer as an edit, but it wasn't big enough: add '-s' option to curl for less noise.

    LATEST_JENKINS_LTS_VERSION=$(curl -s http://...

Comment: Hey @Codex24, yup that is a good idea. I'll add that to the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

They have [RSS](https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/rss.xml) with changelog for latest releases, each post is titled `Jenkins 2.xx`, so maybe you could extract this info from it.